# Expanding content area containing only floating elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble with what are probably some simple floats. I've lined up three forms side-by-side (I've yet to find a way to scale them relative to someone's resolution) and each displays text once expanded. The problem is, the 'content' area of the page only contains the floats, so it doesn't expand to the bottom of the page. How is the best way to achieve this? It may be useful to look at the page [here](http://clio.neocities.org/homilies/homily1.html).

Hopefully this code helps explain my problem:

HTML + Javascript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=eng> 
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px">
        <link href="../normal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="normal" />
        <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../nightview.css" title="nightview">
        <title>CLIO</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="wrap">
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <button type="submit" onclick="switch_style('normal');return false;" name="theme" value="Standard View" class="btnNormal">Standard View</button>
                    <button type="submit" onclick="switch_style('nightview');return false;" name="theme" value="Night View" class="btnNightview">Night View</button>
                </div>
                <header id="header">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a href="../index.html"><h1>Chrysostomus Latinus in Iohannem Online (CLIO)</h1></a>
                        <nav id="nav">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="../index.html">HOME</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../transcriptions.html">TRANSCRIPTIONS</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../login.html">LOGIN</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </header>
                    <div class="content">
   <div class="ex">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm">
            <fieldset>
            <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>CLOSE</span>
                <legend>Select Translation</legend>
                <p>
                  <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
                    <option value="TEXT">Montfaucon</option>
                </select>
                <br>
            <p>
            <input type="button" id="showTxt" value="Select" />
            </p>    
            <output type="text" size="30" name="display" id="display" />
            </p>

            </fieldset>

        </form>
        </div>
<div class="ey">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm2">
            <fieldset>
            <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>CLOSE</span>
                <legend>Select Translation</legend>
                <p>
                <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
                    <option value="TEXT">Montfaucon</option>
                </select>
                <br>
            <p>
            <input type="button" id="showTxt" value="Select" />
            </p>    
            <output type="text" size="30" name="display" id="display" />
            </p>

            </fieldset>

    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="ez">
    <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm3">

        <fieldset>
        <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>CLOSE</span>
            <legend>Select Translation</legend>
            <p>
                <select id="scripts" name="scripts">
                    <option value="TEXT">Burgundio</option>
                    <option value="text">Montfaucon</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <p>
                <input type="button" id="doLoop" value="Select" />
                </p>    
                <output type="text" size="30" name="display" id="display" />
                </p>

        </fieldset>

    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="im">
    <img src="greek.jpg" alt="Greek Translation" height="400" width="400">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="compfooter"><br>
        <a href="homily2.html">NEXT</a>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
(function() {

    // get references to select list and display text box
    var sel = document.querySelectorAll('#scripts');
    var el = document.querySelectorAll('#display');
        var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"');

        sel.forEach(function(elem, i){
        buttons[i].onclick = function(e){
        el[i].value = elem.value;
      };
    })
}());



</script>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    height:relative;
    width: 96.9%;
    background: white;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.99);
    padding: 1.56%;
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    font-size: 1.675em;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    line-height: 100%; 
    margin-bottom: 0.9em;

}

.ex
 {
display:inline-block;
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    float: left;

 }
.ey
 {
display:inline-block;
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    float: left;
 }
.ez
 {
display:inline-block;
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    float: left;
  }
.im
 {
float: left;
  }

form{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 350px;
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    font-size: 0.575em;
    float: left;

}

.compfooter {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -3 em;
  padding: 0%;
  background-color: #222438;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 30%;
}


.compfooter a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.compfooter a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.compfooter a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.compfooter a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
select
 {
  display:auto;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
 } 

#close {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px 2px;
    background:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#close:hover {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px 5px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: ids must be unique, I strongly recommend that ids such as `#display`, `#close`, and `#scripts` be changed into classes. Also you are missing a bracket `var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"');` Never seen nor heard of such a value `height:relative;`

Comment: `font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;` ? try:`font: 27px Slabo, serif;` By doing this: ` font-size: 1.675em; font-size: 1.5vw;` the second property overrides the first...Btw does vw units work well with fonts? I never considered it.

Comment: `display:auto` does not exist. I've been down this rabbit hole before, my advice is to start your CSS over and don't use floats, they are old and delicate. Use flexbox it is you friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to fill the content.

```
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
```